# Typo3 6.2 LTS Upgrade to Version 7.4

Tags: php, linux, nginx, debian, typo3

Current Version: 6.2.9 LTS
Upgrade to: 7.4.0

```
Server Enviroment:
PHP 5.4.44-0+deb7u1 (cli) (built: Aug 16 2015 09:51:53)
Zend Engine v2.4.0
System:         Linux servername.local 3.18.9-x86_64-jb1 #2 SMP Wed Mar 25 16:07:36 CET 2015 x86_64
Server API:     FPM/FastCGI
Server Software:    nginx/1.6.2
mysql  Ver 15.1 Distrib 10.0.21-MariaDB, for debian-linux-gnu (x86_64) using readline 5.2
```

Haven't upgraded a Typo3 installation before. Based on the information, do you recommend to update or should I wait for a new LTS version? 
On the other hand, do you have an advise to do a full upgrade for the server environment including nginx, PHP, mariaDB and Typo3 as well?
It's no problem to upgrade each package manually, because I have root privileges. Also a manual dupgrade for Typo3 is possible.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Short version:**

If you do not need some feature available in 7+ right now, you don't need to upgrade.

**Longer version:**

For sure you should try upgrade "at home" first - not in production, to identify points of failure and avoid them. TYPO3 ver. 7 doesn't bring big feature-set, it's rather planned cleanup branch. Of course changes in Backend layout and performance is noticeable, but from my point of view (experienced, heavy user/developer of TYPO3) there's no bigger reason to upgrade **stable** 6.2 LTS installation ASAP. Must say that at the moment (summer 2015) I'm still starting new projects with latest LTS.

Keep in mind that TYPO3 ver. 7+ **removes** old fashioned classes (i.e. `t3lib_*`) which where marked as `depreciated` in 6.x and where used by *ma(aaa)ny* years in many (most) of public extensions, so before upgrading you need to check one-by-one if these exts are prepared for 7-th version of CMS (for an example [`extension_builder`](https://typo3.org/extensions/repository/view/extension_builder), my every-day tool **is not**). There is big chance that you'll find at least several points which will require manual fixing (see: `typo3/sysext/core/Migrations/Code/LegacyClassesForIde.php` file in your 6.x installation).

Finally when you'll start upgrading remember to upgrade by minor versions i.e. 6.2 > 7.0 > 7.1 > 7.2... etc,  according to [upgrading docs](https://wiki.typo3.org/Upgrade).

Comment: Thanks for your reply. After performing a backup I upgraded PHP to version PHP 5.5.28-1~dotdeb+7.1 (cli) (built: Aug  8 2015 21:58:05) in a non-productive environment. Do you know where I can get the upgrade package for TYPO3? Unfortunately the upgrade documentary doesn't go to deep in that detail:
https://wiki.typo3.org/Upgrade#After_upgrading_2

Comment: You mean Upgrade Wizard? Just replace `typo3` folder and `index.php` to newest one and then log in to the Install Tool

Answer (score 1):

TYPO3 version 7 requires PHP 5.5 at least (see [Download](http://typo3.org/download/) page). So you can't upgrade using that server setup.